Bounding distance to an intersection of semialgebraic sets
As a continuation of my recent question " Bounding distance to an intersection of polyhedra ", I would like to pose a similar question about semialgebraic sets. Namely, given any two semialgebraic sets $P$ and $Q$, are there positive constants $C_{PQ}$ and $\theta_{PQ}$ such that for any point $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ one has a bound
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
\dist(x,P\cap Q)^\theta\leq C_{PQ} \max(\dist(x,P),\dist(x,Q))?
$$
Presumably such a bound would be related to the Lojasiewicz inequality.

You also need convexity for this to be true. Otherwise, a counterexample, e.g.:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
\begin{split}
P &= \{xy<1\},\\ 
Q &= \{(1-x)y<1\}, 
\end{split} (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2
$$
then for $x_n=(1/2, n)$ we have
$$
\max \{\dist(x_n,P),\dist(x_n,Q)\} <1/2
$$ and yet
$$
\dist (x_n, P\cap Q) \to \infty \text{ as } n\to\infty
$$

I may possibly have miswritten the expression for $x_n$: is it perhaps $x_n = \frac{1}{2n}$? Please check my edit.
